# Why jQuery UI Sortable connected lists doesn't work with Angular UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui

I'm trying to use [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.com/) and [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) to mimic the [Connected Lists](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) behavior.

But, the behavior is quite flaky: http://jsfiddle.net/hKYWr/227/
Any ideas?

---

HTML:

```
<div ng:controller="controller">
    <ul class='mysortable' ui:sortable ui:options="{connectWith:'.mysortable'}" ng:model="list1">
        <li ng:repeat="item in list1" class="item">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='mysortable' ui:sortable ui:options="{connectWith:'.mysortable'}" ng:model="list2">
        <li ng:repeat="item in list2" class="item">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <pre ng-bind="list1 | json"></pre>
    <hr>
    <pre ng-bind="list2 | json"></pre>
</div>

<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/master/build/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
```

---

JS:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui']);

myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list1 = ["1", "2", "3"];
    $scope.list2 = ["A", "B", "C"];
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

---

CSS:

```
ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
.item {
    padding: 2px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background: #EEE;
}
```

Comment: were you ever able to get these all playing nicely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next version (v0.4.0) of AngularUI

https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/pull/291

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the default ui-sortable: http://jsfiddle.net/a9fFC/3 But I didn't get the model to reflect the update.

But with [angular-ui-multi-sortable](https://github.com/mostr/angular-ui-multi-sortable) I got it working: http://jsfiddle.net/a9fFC/6/

```
<div ng-controller="controller">
    <ul ui-multi-sortable ng-model="list">
        <li ng-repeat="item in list" class="item">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <div ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui']);

myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

Comment: It looks like these fiddles are broken, would you mind updating them?

Comment: you have to adjust the address of the external resources to use `rawgithub.com`, but I'd recommend using the new versions of all the libraries anyway.

Answer (score -3):

5 bitcoins says it's angular ui, and it's collaterally affecting jquery ui library